# Django Rest Framework: Generate a unique obfuscated ID from ID field

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm currently learning how to build an API for my company. I haven't been doing this for very long at all so I'm basically a junior developer at this point.

Following some tutorials, I got my API up and running on a very basic level using class based views.

Previously, I had 'id' as one of the fields for several of my serializers. My manager didn't like this, and he pointed out it would reveal potentially sensitive information about our business (if you get customer_id = 13 for your JSON, then you can infer there are 12 other customers, if you get job_id = 5433 then you can infer there are 5432 other jobs, etc).

I'm trying to figure out how to add "id" to my serializers' fields without revealing such information, to help with the lookup_args and the urls.

Previously, a customer's URL on the API would have been www.example.com/api/customer/5, 5 being the "pk" in the database, and would return JSON data for that customer.

I'm not sure how to go about using the pk but obfuscating it somehow.

Customer model on models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    @staticmethod
    def get_absolute_url():
        return reverse('details')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name + ', ' + self.contact_name + ' (' + .contact_email + ')'

    class Meta:
        unique_together=(('contact_email','user'),)
```

On serializers.py

```
class CustomerListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='api:customer_list_detail',
        lookup_field='pk'
    )
    delete_url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='api:customer_list_delete',
        lookup_field='pk'
    )
    user = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = [
            'id',
            'url',
            'company_name',
            'contact_name',
            'contact_email',
            'user',
            'delete_url'
        ]
    def get_user(self, obj):
        return str(obj.user.name)
```

What I tried:

id = str(serializers.UUIDField(format=hex))

It just returned the ID same as before. I thought it was a method to generate a unique number but it seems it wasn't the case.

I tried googling for "django rest api generate unique ID" but I'm getting unrelated results or I'm not quite advanced enough to parse through the results and find what I need. As I mentioned, I'm very new at this, but having a lot of fun figuring things out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is an option for your case, but I would suggest that, instead of obfuscating the existing ID field, you could add another unique field to the model: a [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield).

This way, you could pass the 'uuid' to the serializer instead of the 'id', and then use the 'uuid' for the lookup (because it's guaranteed to also be unique). This way, you are not revealing the volume of your data, while still being able to perform your queries.

You should be careful about adding a unique field to an existing model though. Fortunately, there's an example about precisely adding a UUIDField to an existing model in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields).

Hope this helps!